# @if conditional in blade for more than one value

Tags: if-statement, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I currently have this in my blade

```
@if( $generatetypeofSummaryofMembers == 'breakdownMemType' )
    some codes here
@endif
```

How do I write it if I want to put in more than one value, like 'breakdownMemType', 'breakdownStatType', etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if more than one if statement as below.

```
@if($generatetypeofSummaryofMembers == 'breakdownMemType')
   some codes here
@else($generatetypeofSummaryofMembers == 'breakdownStatType')
   some codes here
@end if
```

If you want to use multiple in one if statement you can use || or AND.

Comment: could you edit your answer and show me how to use || or AND?